# Trying to use line styles but see points

Tags: gnuplot

With the following simple data file

```
1 1 
2 3
3 4
```

and this script

```
set style line 2 lt 3 lc rgb "red" lw 3
show style line

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
plot "test_data.txt" u 1:2 ls 1
```

I don't see the line. Instead I only see the points. More than that, I don't see (1 1). Why? I followed the same steps form [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas/dashcolor.html)

[image]

Comment: If you have a lot of plots, you can also use `set style data lines` to plot all following data plots with lines. Likewise, there is e.g. `set style funcition linespoints` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a data file, the example you reference uses functions. In gnuplot you need to specify that you want to use lines (`with lines` or in short `w l`) if you want to join data points with lines. Also, I can see (1 1) on your graph. Also I noticed you defined `style line 2` but then used `ls 1` instead of `ls 2` to plot your data (that is you're not using the style you previously defined). Try

```
plot "test_data.txt" u 1:2 w l ls 2
```

If you *also* want to see the points together with lines, then use `with linespoints` or `w lp`:

```
plot "test_data.txt" u 1:2 w lp ls 2
```

Comment: how can I set dashes or lines with dashes? `w l ls 2` and `w l ls 1` are the same

Comment: `ls` refers to the line style, to get dashed lines you need to use the line type option `lt`, whose effect depends on the terminal you use. In the default terminal, `wxt`, you need to add the option `dashed`, i.e. use `set terminal wxt dashed`, and then the option `lt 2` will give you dashed lines, `lt 3` gives dotted lines, `lt 4`gives dashed-dotted lines, and so on. Not all terminals support dashed lines, but most major ones should.